# Rationality test for a rational power of a rational

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

It has been known since Pythagoras that 2^(1/2) is irrational. It is also obvious that 4^(1/2) is rational. There is also a fun proof that even the power of two irrational numbers can be rational.

Can you, in general, compute whether the power of two rational numbers is rational?

The reason I am asking, besides curiosity, is that the Fraction-type in Python always returns a float on exponentiation. If there is a quick way to tell if it could be accurately expressed as a fraction, the power function could conceivably only return floats when it has to.

EDIT:
By popular demand, I changed 0.5 to 1/2 to make it clearer that it is a fraction and not a float.

Comment: 'the power function could conceivably only return floats when it has to' What would the benefit of that be?

Comment: Also, I assume you mean "is there an algorithm more efficient than evaluating the power expression, and testing if the result is rational?"

Comment: @Marcin: How would you test if the result is rational?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I suppose all floats are rational, by definition.

Comment: It could return a Fraction instead of a float. Fractions are good, exact numbers. Floats are unholy approximations :).

Comment: @Marcin floats are rational approximations of real numbers in computers, but not exact representations of rational numbers - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number

Comment: @deathApril: You're making a distinction without a difference. Once reduced to a floating-point representation, you are dealing with a rational number.

Comment: @Gurgeh: Could you please give an example of where `irrational^irrational = rational`, without complex numbers, if you know of one?

Comment: @deathApril, it depends on whether you're talking about _representations of_ floats or _operations on_ floats.

Comment: @ninjagecko, easy, e ^ ln(10) = 10.

Comment: @senderle: ah, silly me, thank you =)

Comment: @Marcin Fractions and Decimals in python are not reduced to a floating-point representations (the question probably should say `4 ** Fraction(1, 2)` instead of `4^0.5` thought)

Comment: Why the close votes? This isn't off-topic, it was clearly stated as relating to implementing fractions. I personally find it useful.

Comment: @ninjagecko http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/30002.3-5.shtml

Comment: @deathApril: What point are you making? This question is about raising integers to powers, an operation that in python yields a float.

Comment: I suggest that this be migrated back to stackoverflow.com

Comment: @ninjagecko I am pleased that someone recognizes this as related to programming. Why have a (well used) math tag on stackoverflow if math related programming questions does not belong?

Comment: @Gurgeh: though cstheory.stackexchange is also a reasonable forum in the future. Too bad SO isn't like Quora.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no *really* easy way to test if the result of `a ** b` with `a` and `b` being rational numbers is rational.  The easiest way is to decompose `a` into its prime factorisation

```
a = p_0 ** k_0 * p_1 ** k_1 ... p_r ** k_r
```

with `p_i` being prime numbers and `k_i` being (signed) integers.  The result of `a ** b` is rational if all `k_i * b` are integers again.

Comment: An arbitrary rational `a=x/y` doesn't have a prime factorization, but it would be sufficient to test that both `x**b` and `y**b` are rational using this method.

Comment: This begs the question, how do you decompose a into its prime factorisation?

Comment: @chepner: An arbitrary rational *does* have a unique prime factorisation.  The exponents aren't necessarily positive.

Comment: @Gurgeh, if that were easy, we wouldn't have cryptography.

Comment: @Gurgeh: That's a rather [complex topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factorization#Factoring_algorithms).  The most simple approach is to iterate through the numbers `2` to `x // 2` for both numerator and denominator and split off any divisors you find.

Comment: Aha.. now I understand what you mean by prime factorisation, I know that is a hard problem. You threw me with the signed integers, but I understand that is because we have rationals and not integers.

Comment: Is it generally known that there is no faster way to know if a**b is rational? Is the existence of such a method ruled out, because it could help you with prime factorisation?

Comment: @Gurgeh: I don't know, but my number-theoretic intuition strongly suggests there is no easier way.

Comment: I'll trust your intuition then :). Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Oh. Turns out your intuition was wrong. See Bill Dubuque, below.

Answer (score 17):

We can do this much quicker than using prime factorization. Below I show how to reduce the problem to testing if an integer is a (specific) perfect power - i.e. an integer perfect power test.

**Lemma** $\ $ If $\rm\,R\,$ and $\,\rm K/N\:$ are rationals,   $\rm\:K,N\in\mathbb Z,\ \gcd(K,N)=1,\,$ then  $$\rm\:R^{K/N}\in\Bbb Q\iff R^{1/N}\in \mathbb Q\qquad$$

**Proof** $\ (\Rightarrow)\ $ If $\,\rm\color{#0a0}{R^{K/N}\in\Bbb Q},\,$ then by $\rm\:gcd(N,K) = 1\:$ we have a Bezout equation

$$\rm 1 = JN+I\:\!K\, \overset{\!\div\ N}\Rightarrow\  1/N  = J + IK/N\ \Rightarrow\ R^{1/N} =\ R^J(\color{#0a0}{R^{K/N}})^I  \in \mathbb Q$$

$(\Leftarrow)\  \ \rm\:R^{1/N}\in \mathbb Q\ \Rightarrow\ R^{K/N} = (R^{1/N})^K\in \mathbb Q.\ \ \small\bf QED$

So we've reduced the problem to determining if $\rm\:R^{1/N} = A/B  \in \mathbb Q.\,$ If so then $\rm\: R = A^N/B^N\:$ and $\rm\:gcd(A,B)=1\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:gcd(A^N,B^N) = 1,\:$ by unique factorization or Euclid's Lemma. By uniqueness of reduced fractions, this is true iff the lowest-terms numerator and denominator of $\rm\:R\:$ are both $\rm\:N'th\:$ powers of integers.

So we reduce to the problem of checking if an integer is a perfect power. This can be done very quickly, even in the general case, see D. J. Bernstein, [Detecting powers in almost linear time. 1997.](http://cr.yp.to/papers/powers.pdf)

Comment: Fascinating! Was this result known to you, or did you just quickly derive it?

Comment: IMO, reducing $R^{K/N}$ to $R^{1/N}$ is fairly intuitive, and a feasible algorithm to test if an integer is a perfect power is nearly obvious of you think about it. (just keep taking $n$-th roots for every $n$ until you get an integer or something less than 2) The trick is to have both thoughts in your head at the same time.

Comment: Especially if you're going to be marking other questions as duplicates of this one, please **include the algorithm in your answer** rather than linking to it. (Or at least include a simpler algorithm that's not as good, but still efficient.)

Comment: @Misha That has been on my (very long) to-do list for quite some time but, alas, has not yet percolated to top priority.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I think that your assertion that `4^0.5` is rational is arguable.  Bear in mind that in floating-point arithmetic `0.5` represents a range of real numbers, all of whose closest representation in the chosen version of f-p is closer to `0.5` than to either of its neighbouring f-p numbers. Only one of the numbers in that range leads to a rational result for the calculation of `4^0.5`.

It is perfectly reasonable for Python (or any other computer) to, given f-p input, provide f-p output.

Perhaps you should have written *it is obvious that 4^(1/2) is rational* ?

And I see that you already have an answer to your question so I'll stop now.

Comment: 4^0.5 is most certainly rational. But you raise an excellent point. When discussing problems about exact real numbers it's a good idea not to use decimal notation because it suggests you're talking about approximations.

Comment: This is why I mention that I am really talking about Python's Fraction type, which is not a float. The whole point is to avoid floats.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the real answer here is as follows: You don't want to be recovering precision once you've lost it.

For example (as senderle points out) one such `irrational^irrational = rational` example would be `e^ln(10) = 10`. In such a case, you don't want to be working with floats; you want to be working with symbolic math, like a computer algebra system. You look up your rules for exponentiation, and do a search to determine that it simplifies.

---

If you really were forced to lose precision however and try to recover it, and wanted to in this strange context (`irrational^irrational = rational`), and you don't care about being 100% correct, you can do as follows:

1. calculate a**b = c
2. if c is "close to a rational", return that rational

I believe this is used in graphing calculators. Even python's Fraction library uses this technique as `.limit_denominator(...)`. Specifically you say that you will return the "closest" rational, but slightly penalizing rationals which are "complicated" (e.g. number of digits) *compared to the inputs (base and exponent)*. One such algorithm for the "best rational approximation" would use continued fractions, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations (similar to how rational approximations of pi are computed); you could tweak this to penalize guesses which are complicated with respect to the base and exponent.

Thus, I personally would prefer to have the power to simplify mathematical expressions, rather than lose precision and have to recover it. =)

Comment: Note: **This answer was given in response to the question before it was (unreasonably) migrated from stackoverflow.**